# Error on executing proc in mysql insert statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute this proc below and I get an error. please can someone bail me out

### ----

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_class_code`(p_newS varchar(45), p_designation varchar(45))
BEGIN

SET @table_name = p_designation;
SET @new_supply = p_newS;

SET @sql_text = concat('insert into simsed_',@table_name,' (class) values ',@new_supply) ;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

### ----

This is the error i get.

> call insert_class_code('supply 3', 'supplier)
>
> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'supply 3'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your below line have error:

```
SET @sql_text = concat('insert into simsed_',@table_name,' (class) values ',@new_supply) ;
```

Change it with the following code:

```
SET @sql_text = concat('insert into simsed_',@table_name,' (class) values ("',@new_supply,'")') ;
```